# visual studio 2017 slow at renaming textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a medium size project coded in vb.net using latest version of 2017 visual studio.
The problem that I am having right now is that when I edit a textbox say txtCarType to txtCarType2 it takes about 15 seconds to process.
I am also having the same issue with labels or renaming any control. how can I fix this issue this lagging its killing productivity.

Comment: We will need to see some code.  I predict this will get closed if you don't provide a lot more detail.

Comment: it has nothing to do with code.. the UI its the issue here.. while renaming controls

Comment: Oh, OK.  Good luck,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head it could be one of 2 things.

1. It's just running a bit slower because of the size of your application. Trying to sort through all that data takes time, so it's just gonna take a few seconds to find what it needs and change it.
2. Refactoring for all references to the object in your code to prevent errors.

Answer (score 5):

`Visual Studio` is trying to be generous and refactor the new name throughout your project. This indeed helps as if it does not refactor you could be left with some errors. When you rename controls a refactor window pops up as it churns through files to refactor the name through-out the whole project. This indeed can be dreadful, irritating and possibly a long process depending on your solution/projects.

Please give this a shot...

1. Tools --> Options --> Windows Forms Designer (expand node)
2. General --> Refactoring (set "Enable Refactoring on Rename" to **False**)

Hope this helps!